# nftables on Debian: router advertisments are not processed

Tags: debian, ipv6, nftables

I want to filter IPv6 packets on a Debian host using nftables. In the "table ip6 filter" section in "chain input" I use `icmpv6 type {echo-request,nd-neighbor-solicit,nd-router-solicit,mld-listener-query,nd-neighbor-advert,nd-router-advert} accept`
so it should be able to receive and process router advertisments. However, they are still blocked. As soon as I stop the nftables service, IPv6 is working accordingly. My full nftables.conf is [here](https://pastebin.com/iFwX8YK0).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think you should use `inet` and `ip6` at the same time for `filter`. Either use `ip` and `ip6`, or just `inet`. Your rules in the `ip6` table will fit into the `inet` one.

Comment: In case you really just want `iifname lo accept` to apply for IPv6, you can try `iifname lo ip6 daddr ::/0 accept`. (I doubt that it's your intention though.) And the other two rules are already IPv6 specific.

Comment: @TomYan Thank you for the helpful hint with "inet" vs "ip6"! I removed the ip6 section and put the instruction belonging dhcpv6 to the "inet" section and it works now. The "iifname lo accept" should indeed be valid for both protocols, so your assumption was correct.

Answer (score 1):

As Tom Yan pointed out in the comment section, either "inet filter" should be there *or* "ip filter" and "ip6 filter", but *not* "inet filter" and "ip6 filter" at the same time *if* drop policy is being used. So I moved all the IPv6 specific stuff to "inet filter" and removed "ip6 filter" to make this work.

For the full nftables.conf, see [here](https://pastebin.com/qTpGAR5G).

Comment: You can use them both. But not with a drop policy without duplicating rules: when a packet is dropped it disappears for good. whichever table drops the packet will keep it dropped for the other table too. As the inet table drops all icmpv6 (among other things it drops) the ip6 table has nothing left. And if this was done in the other possible order, same: whatever ip6 accepted would be dropped by inet.

Comment: @A.B Thank you for the explanation. I updated my answer to make it more accurate.